# Combining rows into one row with multiple columns of data R

Tags: r, reshape, tidyr

I have a dataset that measures pre and post weight conditions. I was trying to combine rows with similar ID's to one row and create two additional columns to show the results for pre and post for each ID.

Original table

```
ID  Sex         Race        TIME    SH           PRE_WEIGHT POST_WEIGHT
1   FEMALE      White       POST    Poor         168            152
1   FEMALE      White       PRE     Good         168            152
2   MALE        Hispanic    POST    Very Poor    157            143
2   MALE        Hispanic    PRE     Poor         157            143
3   FEMALE      Black       POST    Good         129            118
3   FEMALE      Black       PRE     Satisfactory 129            118
```

Results should look like this:

```
ID  Sex         Race        TIME    SH          PRE_WEIGHT  POST_WEIGHT TIME_PRE    TIME_POST   SH_PRE      SH_POST
1   FEMALE      White       POST    Poor        168         152         POST        PRE         Poor        Good
2   MALE        Hispanic    POST    Very Poor   157         143         POST        PRE         Very Poor   Poor
3   FEMALE      Black       POST    Good        129         118         POST        PRE         Good        Satisfactor
```

I tried to do it with reshape which is very slow and didn't work. I also wasn't able to reshape the table with tidyr.

Hope anyone can help me with this.

Comment: May I ask why you're keeping the original columns `TIME` and `SH` and creating `TIME_PRE` and `TIME_POST` since they add no useful information after you collapse the rows?

Comment: Sorry, yes you are right I just forgot to remove this in the example. There is no need for them.

Comment: Try `df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = TIME,values_from=SH)` loading `tidyverse` package first!

Comment: Thank you, this worked too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Duck mentioned you can do this

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df3 %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = TIME, 
               values_from = SH, 
               names_prefix = "SH_")

#> # A tibble: 3 x 7
#> # Groups:   ID [3]
#>      ID Sex    Race     PRE_WEIGHT POST_WEIGHT SH_POST   SH_PRE      
#>   <dbl> <chr>  <chr>         <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>     <chr>       
#> 1     1 FEMALE White           168         152 Poor      Good        
#> 2     2 MALE   Hispanic        157         143 Very Poor Poor        
#> 3     3 FEMALE Black           129         118 Good      Satisfactory
```

Your data

```r
df3 <- readr::read_table("
ID  Sex         Race        TIME    SH           PRE_WEIGHT POST_WEIGHT
1   FEMALE      White       POST    Poor         168            152
1   FEMALE      White       PRE     Good         168            152
2   MALE        Hispanic    POST    Very Poor    157            143
2   MALE        Hispanic    PRE     Poor         157            143
3   FEMALE      Black       POST    Good         129            118
3   FEMALE      Black       PRE     Satisfactory 129            118")
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), ID + Sex + Race  + PRE_WEIGHT + 
           POST_WEIGHT ~ TIME, value.var = 'SH')
```

-output

```
#   ID    Sex     Race PRE_WEIGHT POST_WEIGHT      POST          PRE
#1:  1 FEMALE    White        168         152      Poor         Good
2#:  2   MALE Hispanic        157         143 Very Poor         Poor
3#:  3 FEMALE    Black        129         118      Good Satisfactory
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple base R option might be using `reshape`, e.g.,

```
reshape(
  df,
  direction = "wide",
  idvar = c("ID","Sex","Race"),
  timevar = "TIME"
)
```

which gives

```
  ID    Sex     Race   SH.POST PRE_WEIGHT.POST POST_WEIGHT.POST       SH.PRE
1  1 FEMALE    White      Poor             168              152         Good
3  2   MALE Hispanic Very Poor             157              143         Poor
5  3 FEMALE    Black      Good             129              118 Satisfactory
  PRE_WEIGHT.PRE POST_WEIGHT.PRE
1            168             152
3            157             143
5            129             118
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), Sex = c("FEMALE", 
"FEMALE", "MALE", "MALE", "FEMALE", "FEMALE"), Race = c("White",
"White", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Black", "Black"), TIME = c("POST", 
"PRE", "POST", "PRE", "POST", "PRE"), SH = c("Poor", "Good",
"Very Poor", "Poor", "Good", "Satisfactory"), PRE_WEIGHT = c(168L,
168L, 157L, 157L, 129L, 129L), POST_WEIGHT = c(152L, 152L, 143L,
143L, 118L, 118L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L
))
```